# Backend integration testing sending firebase push notification

Tags: .net, firebase, push-notification

I have a dotnet application for sending push notifications using firebase where I store the user device token id and then send some notifications.
By default we write functional tests for all of our APIs to make sure everything is working together, however this is currently not possible for this api that sends the push notification because we don't have a valid token id during our tests.
That said, is there any way to generate a valid id token in the backend to use in these tests?